# Why is my array parameter getting forced into a string at position 0 in Powershell?

Tags: arrays, function, powershell

This is a stripped down version of the code I need to run. I've been able to determine, with this test code, that it's happening as soon as the array enters the function. Am I doing something wrong when I pass the array? This seems like it should be simple, but I'm stuck. Doing `Return ,$List` doesn't make any difference.

Script:

```
function ProcessSkills{
    param([Object[]]$List)
    Write-Host $List.GetType()
    Write-Host $List.Count
    Write-Host $List
    $List += 11
    Write-Host $List.GetType()
    Write-Host $List.Count
    Write-Host $List
    return $List
}

$skillList = @()
Write-Host
Write-Host "Start"
Write-Host 
Write-Host $skillList.GetType()
Write-Host $skillList
Write-Host $skillList.Count
$newSkillList = ProcessSkills -$skillList $skillList
$skillList = $newSkillList
Write-Host $skillList.GetType()
Write-Host $skillList
Write-Host $skillList.Count
$newSkillList = ProcessSkills -$skillList $skillList
$skillList = $newSkillList
Write-Host $skillList.GetType()
Write-Host $skillList
Write-Host $skillList.Count
$newSkillList = ProcessSkills -$skillList $skillList
$skillList = $newSkillList
Write-Host $skillList.GetType()
Write-Host $skillList
Write-Host $skillList.Count
```

Output:

```
Start

System.Object[]

0
System.Object[]
1
-
System.Object[]
2
- 11
System.Object[]
- 11
2
System.Object[]
1
-- 11
System.Object[]
2
-- 11 11
System.Object[]
-- 11 11
2
System.Object[]
1
--- 11 11
System.Object[]
2
--- 11 11 11
System.Object[]
--- 11 11 11
2
```

Comment: Can you rephrase what you're asking for? I am genuinely confused.

Comment: The `$` is not part of the parameter name, change all instance of `ProcessSkills -$skillList $skillList` to `ProcessSkills -List $skillList`

Answer (score 1):

Does this address the problem?

```
function ProcessSkills{
    param([Object[]]$List)
    $List += 11
    return ,$List
}

$skillList = @()
$skillList = ProcessSkills  $skillList
$skillList = ProcessSkills  $skillList
$skillList = ProcessSkills  $skillList
```